# Facebook Open Graph Issues / OAuth Connection

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been recently switching over to Open crash for all stream_publish actions and I've noticed a recurring issue:

Object titles are not showing when viewing a post on Mobile, or the Web. I usually see this on the mobile app/web - where the object title isn't being shown, but on the desktop web - it's always there. Is there a character limit on mobile?

### OAuth Connection Issues

In addition - some users are unable to login via Facebook. Every attempt to run through the traditional OAuth server side logic presents this URL:

error_code=2000&error_message=The+specified+feature+has+been+temporarily+disabled

This happens for at least a handful of users. Are there specific permissions that users can block for all OAuth requests?